# Strata Sample Sizes and Stratified Sampling

Tags: sampling, sample-size, stratification

I am trying to conduct a research study on the local population of homeless individuals in my county. But, before I can detail my study, it would be helpful to provide some context.

**Context:** It is hard to know the exact size of the homeless population because the population is relatively dynamic (people move in and out of homelessness). But, I can use proxies for the population, like the point-in-time census count my county conducts once every other year to survey how many people are homeless on a single night. The most recent count conducted indicated that there were roughly 9,000 individuals experiencing homelessness on a single night. The outreach effort also measured the race/ethnicity of each person and the demographic breakdown is as follows:

- American Indian, Alaska Native or Indigenous: 3%
- Asian: 2%
- Black, African American: 39%
- Multiracial: 5%
- Native Hawaiian or Pacific Islander: 2%
- White, Hispanic: 11%
- White, non-Hispanic: 38%

All individuals who reach out for services are evaluated using an assessment.  But, there is interest in updating the assessment with new evaluation questions.

**Research Design:** We would like to randomly sample individuals who reach out for services and determine whether there are significant differences in outcomes for those who take the old assessment versus those who take the new assessment. We've discussed several different approaches (which I won't detail here), but the main question I have is about determining an appropriate sample size. If I calculate the sample size of my finite sample, I get a final projected sample size of 369.  But, I want to make sure that this sample is representative of each racial/ethnic group so I've decided to use a stratified sampling procedure. If I opt for 95% confidence with a 5% margin of error for a population of size 9,000, I get the following stratified sample size for each group (rounding up makes the final sample size 373, instead of 369):

- American Indian, Alaska Native or Indigenous: 11
- Asian: 6
- Black, African American: 146
- Multiracial: 21
- Native Hawaiian or Pacific Islander: 7
- White, Hispanic: 42
- White, non-Hispanic: 140

**Question:** While this sample is representative of the entire population, I worry about only including 6 or 7 individuals who are Asian or Native Hawaiian/Pacific Islander; these smaller strata may not be represented as well as the other groups. *What would be the best way to conduct a stratified sample to ensure all groups are represented, while ALSO ensuring that each individual group has a more meaningful number of participants?*

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Since all groups *are* included in your summary, somehow we have to figure out what a "more meaningful number" is and what you mean specifically by "represented." What criteria do you have in mind? I am guessing you haven't really constructed a stratified design, but have only applied the demographic breakdown to a sample of 369. There are a *lot* of considerations involved here, so you can help us by giving some more information. For starters, what kinds of observations will you be making of these subjects? What do you expect their distributions to be, and how might they vary across strata?

Comment: If you used a proportional random stratification method properly to come up with these counts, then they are equally represented. The question to ask is, are you interested in the population as a whole, or are you concerned more with how minority subpopulations are affected. This is a part of your experimental design which you need to consider like whether or not to stratify by (or focus) on differences based on gender and age. So, you decide, do you want everyone represented proportional to study homelessness generally or are you interested specifically in subpopulations

Comment: One of the main reasons why we are considering this update is because the traditional assessment disproportionately prioritized majority populations over minority populations.  Reading these comments helps me realize that I am especially interested in subpopulation comparisons to help ensure a more equitable prioritization approach.  In this case, I think the existing design works as a way to represent the entire population, but not necessarily promote subpopulation comparisons.  I should probably favored another approach that optimizes for subpopulation comparisons.

Comment: I would expect higher variation in the smaller subpopulations than the larger populations.